# How to get terms names of GADT in Template Haskell?

Tags: haskell, template-haskell

If I have GADT like:

```hs
data Pkt (m::Msg) (d::Dir) where                                                                                        
  GetResourcesPkt :: Pkt 'ResourcesM 'Ask
  MyResourcesPkt :: MyResources -> Pkt 'ResourcesM 'Ans
....
```

how to get in Template Haskell names `GetResolurcesPkt`, `MyResourcesPkt`? I plan to generate case-s in compile time and similar, so I need `MyResourcesPkt` to generate code like:

```hs
case x of
  MyResourcesPkt rs -> ...
```

I think about some function like `getCons 'ResourcesM 'Ask => GetResourcesPkt (as Name?)` or similar. Is it possible at all?
Maybe I need to know their arity too, if it's impossible to do `{}` or `{..}` in TH.

Comment: GADT constructors are just a special case of [data-declaration constructor](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/template-haskell-2.21.0.0/docs/Language-Haskell-TH.html#t:Con) in Template Haskell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can inspect the GADT using `reify` or a package like `th-abstraction` that provides more predictable wrappers around `reify`.

Best practice is probably to use `th-abstraction`, but for your specific example, the way `th-abstraction` handles GADTs might make it more difficult, so maybe you want to stick with `reify`.

I'm not sure how useful a function like `getCons` will be, but here's how you could implement it.

First, as an important debugging tool, it's helpful to know how to dump the result of `reify` to the console.  Unlike many TH functions, `reify` can't be run directly in `IO` (e.g., from the GHCi prompt).  Instead, it needs to run in "real" compile-time Template Haskell code in the `Q` monad, like in the following example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

module Pkt where

import Language.Haskell.TH

data Msg = ResourcesM
data Dir = Ask | Ans
data MyResources

data Pkt (m :: Msg) (d :: Dir) where
   GetResourcesPkt :: Pkt 'ResourcesM 'Ask
   MyResourcesPkt :: MyResources -> Pkt 'ResourcesM 'Ans

do pkt <- reify (mkName "Pkt")
   runIO $ print pkt
   pure []
```

At compile time, this prints the following to the console:

```
$ ghc Pkt.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Pkt              ( Pkt.hs, Pkt.o, Pkt.dyn_o )
TyConI (DataD [] Pkt.Pkt [KindedTV m_6989586621679011365 () (ConT Pkt.Msg),
KindedTV d_6989586621679011366 () (ConT Pkt.Dir)] Nothing [GadtC [Pkt.GetResourcesPkt]
[] (AppT (AppT (ConT Pkt.Pkt) (PromotedT Pkt.ResourcesM)) (PromotedT Pkt.Ask)),
GadtC [Pkt.MyResourcesPkt] [(Bang NoSourceUnpackedness NoSourceStrictness,ConT 
Pkt.MyResources)] (AppT (AppT (ConT Pkt.Pkt) (PromotedT Pkt.ResourcesM)) (PromotedT 
Pkt.Ans))] [])
```

or, reformatted:

```
TyConI (DataD                                     -- data
  []
  Pkt.Pkt                                         --      Pkt
  [ KindedTV m_... () (ConT Pkt.Msg)              --          (m :: Msg)
  , KindedTV d_... () (ConT Pkt.Dir)]             --          (d :: Dir) where
  Nothing
  [ GadtC [Pkt.GetResourcesPkt]                   --   GetResourcePkg ::
          []
          (AppT (AppT
            (ConT Pkt.Pkt)                        --     Pkt
            (PromotedT Pkt.ResourcesM))           --         'ResourcesM
            (PromotedT Pkt.Ask))                  --         'Ask
  , GadtC [Pkt.MyResourcesPkt]                    --   MyResourcesPkt ::
          [( Bang NoSourceUnpackedness
                  NoSourceStrictness
           , ConT Pkt.MyResources)]               --     MyResources ->
          (AppT (AppT
            (ConT Pkt.Pkt)                        --     Pkt
            (PromotedT Pkt.ResourcesM))           --         'ResourcesM
            (PromotedT Pkt.Ans))]                 --         'Ans
  [])
```

So, as a first crack at writing `getCons`, you might try:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

module GetCons where

import Data.List
import Language.Haskell.TH

getCons :: Q Type -> Q Type -> Q (Maybe Name)
getCons qm qd
  = do m <- qm
       d <- qd
       TyConI (DataD _ _ _ _ cns _) <- reify (mkName "Pkt")
       pure $ consName <$> find (match m d) cns
  where consName (GadtC [n] _ _) = n
        match m d (GadtC _ _ (AppT (AppT (ConT _) m') d')) = m==m' && d==d'
```

Then, in a separate module, you can use it on your `Pkt` type:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

module Pkt where

import Data.List
import Language.Haskell.TH
import GetCons

data Msg = ResourcesM
data Dir = Ask | Ans
data MyResources

data Pkt (m :: Msg) (d :: Dir) where
   GetResourcesPkt :: Pkt ResourcesM 'Ask
   MyResourcesPkt :: MyResources -> Pkt 'ResourcesM 'Ans

do c <- getCons [t| 'ResourcesM |] [t| 'Ask |]
   runIO $ print c
   pure []
```

When compiled, this prints the matched constructor name:

```
$ ghc Pkt
[1 of 2] Compiling GetCons          ( GetCons.hs, GetCons.o, GetCons.dyn_o )
[2 of 2] Compiling Pkt              ( Pkt.hs, Pkt.o, Pkt.dyn_o ) [Source file changed]
Just Pkt.GetResourcesPkt
```